# How to parsing the XML by SimpleXML

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I am trying to parse the below `XML` using `SimpleXML` parsing.
I have tried in different ways to parse the `Attributes` of the `Element` but unable to get success in parsing the below XML.
It generates an error that is list at the bottom.

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <order>
    <id>1</id>
    <id_address_delivery xlink:href="http://abc.com/add/1">1</id_address_delivery>
    <id_address_invoice xlink:href="http://abc.com/add/2">2</id_address_invoice>
  </order>
</prestashop>
```

**`Order.java`**

```
@Root(name="order")
@Namespace(reference="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",prefix="xlink")
public class Order {

    @Element(name="id",required=true)
    private int order_id;

    @Element(name="id_address_delivery",required=false)
    private int id_address_delivery;
    @Attribute( name="href", required=false)
    private String id_address_delivery_href;


    @Element(name="id_address_invoice",required=false)
    private int id_address_invoice;
    @Attribute(name="href", required=false)
    private String id_address_invoice_href;
}
```

**`OrderObject.java`**

```
public class OrderObject
{
    @ElementList(required=true, inline=true)
    private List<Order> list = new ArrayList<Order>();

    public List<Order>getList()
    {
        return this.list;
    }
}
```

**Exception that I get is :**

```
WARN/System.err(988): org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: 
Duplicate annotation of name 'href' on field 'id_address_delivery_href' 
private java.lang.String com.prestashop.orders.Order.id_address_delivery_href
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.StructureBuilder.process(StructureBuilder.java:250)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.StructureBuilder.process(StructureBuilder.java:173)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.ObjectScanner.field(ObjectScanner.java:438)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.ObjectScanner.scan(ObjectScanner.java:371)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.ObjectScanner.<init>(ObjectScanner.java:82)
.
.
```

Comment: +1 - will be a helpful question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for this exception are your both `@Attribute` annotations. They aren't set to the next element but to the entire `Order` object. Your annotations would set `href` twice, but with different values.

Please see JavaDoc of [`@Attribute`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Attribute.html):

> The `Attribute` annotation represents a serializable XML attribute
>   within an XML element. [...]

But there's a nice and simple solution: Instead of combining element and attribute, make a class which does this.

### `OrderObject` class:

```java
@Root(name = "prestashop")
@Namespace(reference = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", prefix = "xlink")
public class OrderObject
{
    @ElementList(required = true, inline = true)
    private List<Order> list;


    public OrderObject()
    {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    public List<Order> getList()
    {
        return list;
    }


    // ...

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "OrderObject{" + "list=" + list + '}';
    }

}
```

**Note:** The `toString()` methods in these classes are only implemented to check the result!

### `Order` class:

```java
@Root(name = "order")
public class Order
{
    @Element(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Element(name = "id_address_delivery")
    private AdressDelivery delivery;
    @Element(name = "id_address_invoice")
    private AdressInvoice invoice;


    public Order(int id, AdressDelivery delivery, AdressInvoice invoice)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.delivery = delivery;
        this.invoice = invoice;
    }

    private Order() {  }


    // Getter / Setter etc.


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Order{" + "id=" + id + ", delivery=" + delivery + ", invoice=" + invoice + '}';
    }


    @Root()
    public static class AdressDelivery
    {
        @Namespace(reference = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", prefix = "xlink")
        @Attribute(name = "href", required = false)
        private String link;
        @Text()
        private int value;


        public AdressDelivery(String link, int value)
        {
            this.link = link;
            this.value = value;
        }

        AdressDelivery() { }



        // Getter / Setter etc.

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "AdressDelivery{" + "link=" + link + ", value=" + value + '}';
        }
    }

    @Root()
    public static class AdressInvoice
    {
        @Attribute(name = "href", required = false)
        @Namespace(reference = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", prefix = "xlink")
        private String link;
        @Text()
        private int value;


        public AdressInvoice(String link, int value)
        {
            this.link = link;
            this.value = value;
        }

        AdressInvoice() { }


        // Getter / Setter etc.

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "AdressInvoice{" + "link=" + link + ", value=" + value + '}';
        }
    }

}
```

You can see the `AdressDelivery` and `AdressInvoice` classes which combine attribute and element. You do not have to implement them as inner classes; feel free to write them as "normal" one. You also do not have to make them public, even private is possible (eg. construct them within the `Order`'s constructor.

But please note the empty constructors without arguments in `Order` class (and it's inner classes). They are *required*. But you can make all of them `private` - no need to expose them. It's only important that you *have* a constructor without arguments.

### How to use *(example)*:

```java
File f = new File("whatever.xml");

Serializer ser = new Persister();
OrderObject orderObject = ser.read(OrderObject.class, f);

System.out.println(orderObject);
```

This code parses the Xml from file and prints the deserialized object.

**Input Xml *(as in your question)*:**

```xml
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <order>
    <id>1</id>
    <id_address_delivery xlink:href="http://abc.com/add/1">1</id_address_delivery>
    <id_address_invoice xlink:href="http://abc.com/add/2">2</id_address_invoice>
  </order>
</prestashop>
```

**Result *(from `println()`)*:**

```
OrderObject{list=[Order{id=1, delivery=AdressDelivery{link=http://abc.com/add/1, value=1}, invoice=AdressInvoice{link=http://abc.com/add/2, value=2}}]}
```

Not clearly represented, but enough to see the result :-)

Comment: I appreciate your effort..!
And your answer is very close to the solution that I had found yesterday.. :-)